# Corda 4.3 compilation issues

Tags: corda

Trying to compile Corda from scratch. I cloned version 4.3 from Github. Details and error codes below.I am using Oracle java version 1.8. I have asked this question on slack as well but didn't find anyone who has faced this issue before.

> Task :node-api-tests:test
>   net.corda.nodeapitests.internal.crypto.X509UtilitiesTest > create valid server certificate chain FAILED
>     java.security.cert.CertificateException at X509UtilitiesTest.kt:166
>   net.corda.nodeapitests.internal.crypto.X509UtilitiesTest > create valid self-signed CA certificate FAILED
>     java.security.cert.CertificateException at X509UtilitiesTest.kt:131
>   46 tests completed, 2 failed
>   Task :node-api-tests:test FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ‘:node-api-tests:test’.

Comment: Are you trying to build a Cordapp?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're trying to build Corda's source code. Most of the time you really won't need to do this. I'd recommend instead just taking a look at the Corda samples as they use gradle which will download the jars and compile the samples for you.

Here's a link to some of those sample repo's so you can try building off of them.

https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin
https://github.com/corda/samples-java

All of them compile and run the same way so it shouldn't be too difficult to get running.

./gradlew deployNodes

and then 
./build/nodes/runnodes